# In Linux, when does the "bash" command source a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile file?

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently using ssh to access a linux computer. I use the command:

```
ssh -t user@hostaddress 'cd ~/Desktop && bash'
```

When I get there, I see that neither `~/.bash_profile` nor `~/.profile` are sourced. What are the rules surrounding when these are sourced in? The reason I call bash is because I am able to get terminal colors when I do bash (blue folders, etc) that I otherwise cannot get just by using `ssh user@hostaddress`.

Comment: [`man bash`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running `bash` as a login shell -- using `bash -l` should source `.bash_profile`. Otherwise you can use `.bashrc`.